# Jenkins pipeline - Perforce p4jenkins plugin always finds old changes as new when polling

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job that uses the p4jenkins plugin to poll a perforce stream for changes. The polling itself does seem to work, but when polling, it keeps finding the same changelists as new over and over again.

The polling interval is set as:

```
H/2 * * * * # short interval for testing purposes
```

My Jenkins pipeline checkout step (using a shared global library):

```
def call(body) {

def config=[:]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()

//checkout from p4 based on provided stream
checkout([
changelog: true,
poll: true,
scm: [
        $class: 'PerforceScm',
        credential: 'my_p4_service_creds',
        populate : [
        $class: 'AutoCleanImpl',
        delete: false,
        modtime: false,
        parallel: [
                     enable: false,
                     minbytes: '1024',
                     minfiles: '1',
                     path: '/my/path/to/local/p4/bin/p4',
                     threads: '4'],
                     pin '',
                     quiet: false,
                     replace: true
                     ],
        workspace: [
                     $class: 'StreamWorkspaceImpl',
                     charset: 'none',
                     format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}',
                     pinHost: false,
                     streamName: 

"//${config.streamDepot}/${config.stream}"
                         ]
    ]
])
}
```

At first, I thought it maybe was picking up the same changes over and over because they were pending changelists, but I've also tried making sure the stream only contains changelists that can be synced directly to a workspace.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the stream in question a "task stream"? Is the Jenkins workspace "switched" to the stream in question?

Comment: The stream in question is a mainline stream, and the jenkins workspace is not switched to the stream - the p4jenkins plugin creates a client and performs the checkout with the "general scm checkout" pipeline step.